# Prove that $f(x) = 3-\cos(x)$ for all $x\in [0,\pi]$

Tags: calculus

Suppose that $f(x)$ is differentiable everywhere such that

$f(0) = 2$, $f(\pi)=4$ and $f'(x)\ge\sin(x)\quad \forall x.$

then prove that $f(x) = 3-\cos(x)$ for all $x \in [0, \pi]$

Comment: @ChrisCuster I rollbacked your edit since this had made the question nonsense.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what "differentiable of $f(x)≥\sin(x)∀x$ " means.

Comment: @BernardMassé: Perhaps it means "derivative of $f(x) $" ie $f'(x) \geq \sin x, \forall x$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: let $\,g(x)=f(x)-3+\cos(x)\,$, then the problem can be restated as "*given $\,g(0)=g(\pi)=0\,$ and $\,g'(x)\ge 0\,$ then prove that $\,g(x) = 0\,$ on $\,[0,\pi]\,$*".

Comment: So because eventually we can show that g′(x)≥0 works we can say it is proven?

Comment: @Applepie No. You are *given* that $\,g'(x) \ge 0\,$, and you must use that plus the other premises to prove that $\,g(x) = 0\,$.

Comment: dxiv, i get this nice idea, if it increases then it must decrease, but $g'(x)\ge 0$ so it cant decrease so it must be constant, how is it written properly. Thanks!

Comment: $g$ is non-decreasing since $g' \ge 0$, so $g(0) \le g(x) \le g(\pi)$ for all $0 \le x \le \pi$.